# Count instances of value within overlapping dates?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that includes `start_date` and `end_date` for a given `unit_id` along with the unit's `group`.

```
in_df <- data.frame(unit_id = c(1,2,3),
                 start_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01","2019-02-05","2020-01-12")),
                 end_date = as.Date(c("2019-02-06","2019-02-28","2020-01-30")), 
                 group = c("pass","fail","pass"))
```

For each `unit_id`, I need to calculate the proportion of all units that `pass` within the duration, `start_date` and `end_date` for the current `unit_id`.

Taking `unit_id=1` as an example, I need to find all units that have `start_date` and/or `end_date` within the dates for `unit 1`, i.e. `start_date = 2019-01-01` and `end_date = 2019-02-06`. Given my `in_df`, this would return two `units`, `1` and `2`. One unit passes and one fails so the proportion of pass would be `0.5`. `desired_df` shows the output I expect for this example.

```
desired_df <- data.frame(unit_id = c(1,2,3),
                 start_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01","2019-02-05","2020-01-12")),
                 end_date = as.Date(c("2019-02-06","2019-02-28","2020-01-30")), 
                 group = c("pass","fail","pass"),
                 pass_prop = c(0.5,0.5,1))
```

**What I've tried**

There are a lot of existing posts related to identifying overlapping dates. I've tried to work through some to see if I can figure this out but haven't been successful.

The following is the closest that I've gotten. It does what I want on my toy example but not on the real data (additional example data below).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ivs)

in_df <- data.frame(unit_id = c(1,2,3),
                 start_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01","2019-02-05","2020-01-12")),
                 end_date = as.Date(c("2019-02-06","2019-02-28","2020-01-30")), 
                 group = c("pass","fail","pass"))


desired_df <- data.frame(unit_id = c(1,2,3),
                 start_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01","2019-02-05","2020-01-12")),
                 end_date = as.Date(c("2019-02-06","2019-02-28","2020-01-30")), 
                 group = c("pass","fail","pass"),
                 pass_prop = c(0.5,0.5,1))

in_df <- in_df %>%
  mutate(
    start_dt = as.Date(start_date),
    end_dt = as.Date(end_date)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    range = iv(start_dt, end_dt),
    .keep = "unused"
  )

in_df$row_n <- 1:nrow(in_df)

in_df <- in_df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(groupDate = iv_identify_group(range)) %>%
  group_by(groupDate, .add = TRUE)

groupCount <- in_df %>% group_by(groupDate) %>% dplyr::summarize(totalCount=n())
durationCount <- in_df %>% group_by(groupDate,group) %>% dplyr::summarize(groupCount=n())

durationCount <- dplyr::inner_join(groupCount,durationCount, by = "groupDate") 
durationCount$pass_prop <- durationCount$groupCount/durationCount$totalCount
durationCount <- filter(durationCount, group == "pass")
desired_df <- dplyr::full_join(in_df,durationCount, by = "groupDate")             
desired_df
```

[image]

The above displays exactly what I need under `pass_prop`. The problem with this is that `iv_identify_group` extends the `groupDate` too far when additional dates overlap as shown below.

Take `unit = 1` as an example again. If I add another row to `in_df` that overlaps with `unit = 1` and `unit = 3`, then the `groupDate` gets extended to include the ranges for `units` `1`,`2`, and `4`. This happens because `unit 1` overlaps with `2` and `2` overlaps with `4`. I want it to stop at the overlap with `unit 2` since the range of `unit 1` does not overlap with `unit 4`. Below displays this undesired output.

```
in_df <- data.frame(unit_id = c(1,2,3,4),
                    start_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01","2019-02-05","2020-01-12","2019-02-20")),
                    end_date = as.Date(c("2019-02-06","2019-02-28","2020-01-30","2020-01-30")), 
                    group = c("pass","fail","pass","pass"))
# execute same code as above
```

[image]

Comment: I think a range can have the following relationships with another range: no overlap, partial overlap, exact overlap, the first encompasses the second, or the second encompasses the first. Which of these should be included?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
library(dplyr)
in_df %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
    in_df, by = c("start_date" = "end_date", "end_date" = "start_date"),
    match_fun = list(`<=`, `>=`)) %>%
  group_by(unit_id = unit_id.x, start_date = start_date.x,
           end_date = end_date.x, group = group.x) %>%
  summarize(pass_prop = sum(group.y == "pass") / n(), .groups = "drop")
```

Result

```
  unit_id start_date end_date   group pass_prop
    <dbl> <date>     <date>     <chr>     <dbl>
1       1 2019-01-01 2019-02-06 pass        0.5
2       2 2019-02-05 2019-02-28 fail        0.5
3       3 2020-01-12 2020-01-30 pass        1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ivs can help you, but I think you might be looking for `iv_locate_overlaps()` here:

```r
library(ivs)
library(tidyverse)

# Starting with the more complex example with the 4th row
in_df <- tibble(unit_id = c(1,2,3,4),
                start_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01","2019-02-05","2020-01-12","2019-02-20")),
                end_date = as.Date(c("2019-02-06","2019-02-28","2020-01-30","2020-01-30")), 
                group = c("pass","fail","pass","pass"))

in_df <- in_df %>%
  mutate(range = iv(start_date, end_date), .keep = "unused")

in_df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   unit_id group                    range
#>     <dbl> <chr>               <iv<date>>
#> 1       1 pass  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-06)
#> 2       2 fail  [2019-02-05, 2019-02-28)
#> 3       3 pass  [2020-01-12, 2020-01-30)
#> 4       4 pass  [2019-02-20, 2020-01-30)

# "find all units that have `start_date` and/or `end_date` within the dates for unit i"
# So you are looking for "any" kind of overlap.
# `iv_locate_overlaps()` does: "For each `needle`, find every location in `haystack`
# where that `needle` has ANY overlap at all"
locs <- iv_locate_overlaps(
  needles = in_df$range, 
  haystack = in_df$range, 
  type = "any"
)

# Note `needle` 1 overlaps `haystack` locations 1 and 2 (which is what you said
# you want for unit 1)
locs
#>    needles haystack
#> 1        1        1
#> 2        1        2
#> 3        2        1
#> 4        2        2
#> 5        2        4
#> 6        3        3
#> 7        3        4
#> 8        4        2
#> 9        4        3
#> 10       4        4

# Slice `in_df` appropriately, keeping relevant columns needed to answer the question
needles <- in_df[locs$needles, c("unit_id", "range")]
haystack <- in_df[locs$haystack, c("group", "range")]
haystack <- rename(haystack, overlaps = range)

expanded_df <- bind_cols(needles, haystack)
expanded_df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    unit_id                    range group                 overlaps
#>      <dbl>               <iv<date>> <chr>               <iv<date>>
#>  1       1 [2019-01-01, 2019-02-06) pass  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-06)
#>  2       1 [2019-01-01, 2019-02-06) fail  [2019-02-05, 2019-02-28)
#>  3       2 [2019-02-05, 2019-02-28) pass  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-06)
#>  4       2 [2019-02-05, 2019-02-28) fail  [2019-02-05, 2019-02-28)
#>  5       2 [2019-02-05, 2019-02-28) pass  [2019-02-20, 2020-01-30)
#>  6       3 [2020-01-12, 2020-01-30) pass  [2020-01-12, 2020-01-30)
#>  7       3 [2020-01-12, 2020-01-30) pass  [2019-02-20, 2020-01-30)
#>  8       4 [2019-02-20, 2020-01-30) fail  [2019-02-05, 2019-02-28)
#>  9       4 [2019-02-20, 2020-01-30) pass  [2020-01-12, 2020-01-30)
#> 10       4 [2019-02-20, 2020-01-30) pass  [2019-02-20, 2020-01-30)

# Compute the pass proportion per unit
expanded_df %>%
  group_by(unit_id) %>%
  summarise(pass_prop = sum(group == "pass") / length(group))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   unit_id pass_prop
#>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1       1     0.5  
#> 2       2     0.667
#> 3       3     1    
#> 4       4     0.667
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>